# Want to use chart which gives you difference of something in charting library javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts

I am working on Dashboard application. We are using Angular framework.
In a requirement I come up with I chart to implement.

I can use any charting library. But kendo UI or D3 JS is applicable if possible.

I want to use Chart as attachment.

I try to find out something, But I am not getting.

Please provide me any link if any body implemented.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Angular version of Highcharts](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)

It has been highly used Graph API.

**Below are the steps to configure Angular HighCharts API inside your  app**

Install with **bower/npm**:

bower install highcharts-ng

Add references to highcharts/highstocks

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);
```

Add Highcharts to your angular app config

Comment: +1.. I really appreciate your suggestion. But I am already using kendo and D3 with angular. Where i am stuck I want to use chart like I have attached the Image. I am not able to find one.

Comment: I want to use chart like I have attached as a Image. I am not able to find out one. If you have any idea how to use that chart please suggest....

Comment: You can refer this link http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-charting-directives-using-angularjs-d3-js/